# What is the best way to communicate via RESTful-Http with an web-service from an iPhone App

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, afnetworking

My iphone App should be able to communicate with a Webserver via RESTful HTTP.
So now i want to figure out what is the best approach of doing this. Is there a lightweight framework out there which which provides the functionality i want ? With functionality i mean : doing simple http requests with a few lines of code. I read a lot about RESTkit and testet it inside my Project but after upgrading to 0.20 everything seems really confusing to me.

So my question is :
What is the best approach of communicating from an iPhone with a Webservice via RESTFul Http ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to communicate with a Web service for a simple task without local caching (i.e offline access to the data), simply go with [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

If you need to communicate with a Web service and also need mapping to objects and caching to Core Data in your app, trust me, [Restkit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) will save you A LOT of time at the long run. My app is built around a web service and once configured properly, it's a joy to work with, especially the new version (0.2.x).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, my approach is to use NSURLConnection, Grand Central Dispatch and NSJSONSerialization. I write a web service class for each project with simple convenience functions reflecting the needs of each individual app. I of course reuse some of the code across projects, but I don't make any concious effort to write reusable code.

I too have tried RESTKit and found it too confusing/complicated to use.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use just NSURLConnection from standard SDK of iOS. It has not less or much more then I need.